# How can I trigger Pipeline CI/CD using GitLab CI or Jenkins when a user click on button in application?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

For example when a user clicks on the button sign up I want to trigger a pipeline CI/CD

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins trigger has an option of triggering via API,
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/
You can use this and this shall work for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering Mr.Aditya